# Mule 4 - OAuth authorization dance not yet performed for resourceOwnerId in Sharepoint Connector

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal, mule4, mule-esb, mule-connector

I am using Sharepoint Connector in Mule 4 to get file content using OAuth 2.0.

**Under Azure AD I registered a new app** and perform the following steps:

- Got my Client (Application) Id
- Got my App Id URI
- Generated Client Secret
- Got my Tenant Id
- Configured the redirect URI and scopes

After registering my new app I am setting up API permissions for Sharepoint. For app type, I am selecting **Application Permissions** as my app is running as a background service and doesn't require any signed-in user to be present.

Granted all the permissions for Microsoft Graph and Sharepoint with Admin Consent.

Sharepoint connector in Mule requires scope and resourceOwnerId. As scope value, I am passing the scope name which I have created while registering my app. For resourceOwnerId below is the string format I am passing **ResourceId/mypoc2022.sharepoint.com@TenantId**.

For **Scope** below are the values I have tried:

- Employees.Read.All (created new scope while registering new app)
- api://<MY_CLIENT_ID>/Employees.Read.All

For **ResourceId** below are  the values I have tried:

- https://graph.microsoft.com
- 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000
- 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
- API Id URI

Tried toggling the SSL certification validation while setting up the configuration properties for Sharepoint but still got the following error after starting my server.

```
OAuth authorization dance not yet performed for resourceOwnerId
```

Note: While hitting **http://localhost:8081/authorize** I am able to receive the authorization code. But not using the Mulesoft connector. I am not allowed to use the browser as manual intervention is not allowed.

Below is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:sharepoint="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint/current/mule-sharepoint.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="1df5227d-0a5d-40d2-a79b-dac07224dcd4" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <sharepoint:sharepoint-online-config name="Sharepoint_Sharepoint_online" doc:name="Sharepoint Sharepoint online" doc:id="74e86dd4-c0f4-46a8-a375-d239d002fd9e" >
        <sharepoint:oauth-authorization-code-connection siteUrl="https://mypoc2022.sharepoint.com" disableCnCheck="true">
            <sharepoint:oauth-authorization-code consumerKey="GENERATED_CLIENT_ID" consumerSecret="GENERATED_CLIENT_SECRET" authorizationUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID_PASSED_HERE>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" accessTokenUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID_PASSED_HERE>/oauth2/v2.0/token" scopes="https://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" resourceOwnerId="https://graph.microsoft.com/https://mypoc2022.sharepoint.com@TENANT_ID_PASSED_HERE" after="sp-pocFlow" />
            <sharepoint:oauth-callback-config listenerConfig="HTTP_Listener_config" callbackPath="/callback" authorizePath="/authorize" externalCallbackUrl="http://localhost:8081/callback"/>
        </sharepoint:oauth-authorization-code-connection>
    </sharepoint:sharepoint-online-config>
    <flow name="sp-pocFlow" doc:id="980aca08-56fe-42fd-a5d2-470b80e357c8" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="45f0a24f-444d-4a06-b0a4-368968e56f2d" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/api"/>
        <sharepoint:file-get-content doc:name="File get content" doc:id="fdb714ce-ed3c-4bb0-8366-63ee277af8bc" config-ref="Sharepoint_Sharepoint_online" fileServerRelativeUrl="/Shared Documents/sample.pdf"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```